# Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100 keeps getting Status 7 when installing CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom

I'm trying to install CyanogenMod rom on my Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100.

- I have root (checked with root basic app).
- Successfully installed SuperSU Pro.
- Downloaded the third+fourth Cyanogenmon from here: http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i9100&type=nightly (I tried installing both files since the first wasnt installed)

And it gave me the Status 7 error.

- I edited the first part of the "updater-script" file as said in any tutorial on the web and tried to install - I got the same message.
- I tried enabling "Toggle Signature Verification" and still doesn't install it.

What can I do?

Am I doing something wrong?

Am I using wrong versions?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to go to the developer site and file a report?

Comment: So there isn't a problem on my side of the process? 
Where is the developers site?

Comment: Here is a [FIX](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302599) I found for you. *Read thoroughly.* This should solve your problem, if it does I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN "Double check that the Rom/Mod you are flashing matches your phone model." 
Am I downloading the right one for sure from what you see?
I'm downloading Samsung Galaxy S II (Intl) - i9100 / nightly
http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i9100&type=nightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [FIX](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302599) I found for you. *Read thoroughly.* This will solve your problem.

The first mistake that most people make is flashing incorrect/old/outdated version of recovery.

The second mistake is not matching the correct/proper ROM/firmware to the device hardware.

Incompatibilities when flashing account for the majority of failed installations.

***`Always make backups/nandroids`***